# How to make a backwards-compatible Titanium module?

Tags: titanium, appcelerator, titanium-modules

Title says it all: is it possible to make Titanium modules that are backwards-compatible with Titanium apps that are lower than 7.0.0GA?

I tried to set the `minsdk` value in `manifest` for my module to 6.0.4GA but Appcelerator doesn't allow me to add it for apps lower than 7.0.0GA.

How can I make a backwards-compatible Titanium module built with Titanium 7.0.0GA?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you need to compile your module with `apiversion` 4, it has to be minSdk 7.0.0

However, you can easily recompile the module again for lower versions. So, lower `apiversion` to 3 and set minsdk to 6.0.0, and you can use it in TiSDK 6.

It not really is backwards compatible, but just having 2 builds (and 2 versions) should be fine. You could even include them both in your app and just switch based on SDK you use.

I'd recommend changing the major version by 1 though, so for SDK 6 version 1.0, and for SDK 7, make it version 2.0

Comment: But I see that the author of this tool has a backwards-compatible module: https://github.com/benbahrenburg/benCoding.Android.Tools

how was it achieved?

Comment: He didn't offer a build for 7.0 yet, the 6.0 build is a year old. So... its not

Comment: Build it from source. Check out this commit: https://github.com/benbahrenburg/benCoding.Android.Tools/commit/7d7edad47c2c363aee89292de2427a49e10f33ec

It works on my 7.0.0 example app.